# How to remove certain words from url slug

Tags: slug, php

Trying to create a SEO plugin, that will remove stop words from slugs.

This is how to `explode` the `$slug` into a list, and explode the variable containing the stop words :

```
add_filter ('sanitize title', 'remove_false_words');
function remove_false_words($slug) {
    if (!is_Admin()) return $slug;

    $slug = explode ('-', $slug);

    foreach ($slug as $key => $word) {
        //The $slug has been exploded and retrieves its value

        $keys_false = 'a,above,the,also';
        $keys = explode (',', $keys_false);

        foreach ($keys as $1 => $wordfalse) {
            if ($word == $wordfalse) {
                unset ($slug[$k]);
            }
        }
    }
    return implode ('-', $slug);
}
```

Is it correct to `unset` the value here? Or should I use a different way of achieving the same result?

Comment: `$keys_false` is a string right now. Is that right? Should be array I think

Comment: @GhostToast : mattnewbie explodes the string on the next line-- unnecessary step but it isn't broken.

Comment: Oh yes. I forget about `explode()` as I only ever find my self using it's evil twin, `implode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem with `unset`. There is your answer. What matters with a filter is what you return and `unset`ing those keys before your rebuild the string and return it, works.

You are doing too much processing by `explode`ing your `$keys_false` inside a loop, and you have a typo, and you are better off just making an array instead of creating a string that you convert to an array, and PHP has a function to do what your loop is doing. I reorganized it for you.

```
function remove_false_words($slug) {
  if (!is_admin()) return $slug;
  $keys_false = array('a','and','above','the','also');
  $slug = explode ('-', $slug);
  $slug = array_diff($slug,$keys_false);
  return implode ('-', $slug);
}
var_dump(remove_false_words('a-boy-and-his-dog')); // proof of concept
```

Comment: Thank-you. I have been looking as some wordpress snippets that I found on the internet, make need to re-think how I study. As this was one of the snippets I found, & obviously isn't very good.

Comment: PHP suffers from being a "copy and paste and hack together without knowing what you are doing" language. There is a lot of a bad stuff out there.

Comment: this could be simpler, just use str_replace. No explode, no array_diff.
The only difference is that in your $keys_false array, the words need a preceding dash.
Also str_replace has a benefit, you can specify "-long-combos-you-dont-want" without removing "long,"combos", "you", "dont", "want" from everywhere. Cool feats.